# Not getting JS Functionality

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, javascript-objects

In this **Hourly Stop Watch** Dynamic Web Application, I want to achieve the given functionality using JS. below is the functionality

The timer should be initiated at 0.

- When the HTML button element with the id `startBtn` is clicked, the timer should be started.
- When the HTML button element with the id `stopBtn` is clicked, the
  timer should be stopped.
- When the HTML button element with the id `startBtn` is clicked after the HTML button element with id `stopBtn` clicked, the timer should be resumed.
- Timer should reset to 00 minutes, 00 seconds after one hour.

**Note:-**    This is a one hour timer. The maximum time is one hour.

This is the output image:

[image: Hourly Stop Watch Image]

Below is the code that I tried:

```js
let minutesEl = document.getElementById("minutes");
let secondsEl = document.getElementById("seconds");
let startBtnEl = document.getElementById("startBtn");
let stopBtnEl = document.getElementById("stopBtn");

startBtnEl.onclick = function() {
    let counter = 0;
    let intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        counter = counter + 1;
        secondsEl.textContent = counter;
    }, 1000);
};

stopBtnEl.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
};
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&family=Caveat:wght@400;700&family=Lobster&family=Monoton&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap");

.timer {
  font-size:36px  
}
 
.button {
  color:#ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:5px 15px;
  border:none;
}

.bg-start-button {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.bg-stop-button {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="text-center">
    <p class="timer">
      <span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>
     </p>
    <button class="bg-start-button button" id="startBtn">
      Start
    </button>
    <button class="bg-stop-button button" id="stopBtn">
      Stop
    </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the actual problem/question? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add that information _in your question_ and not only in a comment (after someone asked you about it). Also what have you tried so far to solve this on your own? And please ask one question/problem only per question.

Comment: @ Brian Tompsett how can i put output image that you modified for asked question

Answer (score 0):

You define your intervalID in the scope of the function, so your stop function does not have access to it.

Define it outside.

```js
let minutesEl = document.getElementById("minutes");
let secondsEl = document.getElementById("seconds");
let startBtnEl = document.getElementById("startBtn");
let stopBtnEl = document.getElementById("stopBtn");
let intervalId;

startBtnEl.onclick = function() {
    let counter = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(function(){
      counter = counter + 1;
      secondsEl.textContent = counter;
    }, 1000);
};

stopBtnEl.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
};
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bree+Serif&family=Caveat:wght@400;700&family=Lobster&family=Monoton&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Playfair+Display+SC:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap");

.timer {
  font-size:36px  
}
 
.button {
  color:#ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:5px 15px;
  border:none;
}

.bg-start-button {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.bg-stop-button {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="text-center">
    <p class="timer">
      <span id="minutes">00</span>:<span id="seconds">00</span>
     </p>
    <button class="bg-start-button button" id="startBtn">
      Start
    </button>
    <button class="bg-stop-button button" id="stopBtn">
      Stop
    </button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok sir, but how to set the timer should reset to 00 minutes, 00 seconds after one hour.

Comment: This is a one hour timer. The maximum time is one hour <- how to do this functionality